# How to integrate $\int_0^x \frac{t}{(1-t)^2}dt $?

Tags: calculus

How do you integrate $\int_0^x \frac{t}{(1-t)^2}dt $?

My approach was to use partial fractions for $\frac{t}{(1-t)^2}$. I thus have to rewrite $\frac{t}{(1-t)^2}$ as $\frac{t}{(t-1)^2}$(right?) and then integrate:

$\frac{1}{(t-1)}+\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}$

But then the first term gives me: $ \ln(t-1)\Big|_0^x $, which seems to be wrong?

(The derivative of $\ln (1-x)+\frac{x}{1-x}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$. So that should be the desired result.)

Comment: It should be $\ln|t-1|$. The absolute value is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your method of partial fractions:

$$\int{\left(\frac{1}{t-1}+\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}\right)}dt=\ln|t-1|-\frac{1}{t-1}+C$$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^x{\left(\frac{1}{t-1}+\frac{1}{(t-1)^2}\right)}dt&=\ln|x-1|-\frac{1}{x-1}-ln(1)+\frac{1}{0-1} \\
&= \ln|x-1|-\frac{1}{x-1}-1 \\
&= \ln|x-1|-\frac{x}{x-1}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Set $1-t=u$ and then change the original integral.

Answer (score 2):

Better just to substitute $t \mapsto 1-u$ to get

$$\int_{1-x}^1 du \, \frac{1-u}{u^2}$$

Comment: Thanks! but the integral should be $\int\frac{u-1}{u^2}$ ($dx=-du$)
/Alexander

Comment: @Alexander: I reversed the order of the integration limits, so this is OK.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_0^x \frac{t}{(1-t)^2}dt=\int_0^x \frac{t-1+1}{(1-t)^2}dt=-\int_0^x\frac{1}{(1-t)}dt+\int_0^x (1-t)^{-2}dt\\=\left[\log(1-t)+(1-t)^{-1}\right]_0^x=\frac{1}{1-x}+\log(1-x)-1$$

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right man . Be confident .
Use partial fractions and the answer comes out to be ln|x-1| + 1/x-1

Zetasurro you missed on a negative sign while integrating the second part.